# How can I update text on alert controller's UITextField from the pickerView didSelectRow delegate method?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview, uialertcontroller

I want to update a UITextField inside a UIAlertController when my UIPickerView scrolls.

I tried to add a tag on my textfield:

```
myTextField.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.inputView = self.myPickerView
        textField.tag = 2
        textField.delegate = self
})
```

For the pickerView delegate method `didSelectRow` I declared a ivar `pickerViewName` to store the row's name:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    pickerViewName = myArray[row].name
    //Update UITextField text here, but unable to get it's tag.
}
```

and on the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if (textField.tag == 2)
    {
        textField.text = pickerViewName!
    }

}
```

It isn't working however. When I scrolled up and down the textfield does not update. Much appreciated if you could help me point out where my mistake is! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are doing following: if the picker scrolls you assign a new name to the variable. However you never call update for the textfield. Your name is assigned after you start editing text field. I am not sure if this is desired, otherwise you will have to call it manually.

Comment: I added the delegate for my textfield. The problem is I can't get the textfield and change it's text in the `didSelectRow` method. I tried `self.view.viewWithTag` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Of course it will not work. UIAlertController has its own view. If you want to get it, you will need to do `myTextField.view.viewWithTag`

Comment: Much thanks, that worked. I had to put my UIAlertController outside of my method to access it however.

Comment: But in your situation, I would rather get a reference to textfield than an alert view itself. If you found that helpful, please mark it as a correct answer.